# Need a section "Questions that were edited after they were closed" in review screen

Tags: feature-request, review, vote-to-reopen, on-hold

I think we could really do with a section in the review page which shows all questions that were edited by the owners after they were closed (put on hold), in an attempt to improve them.

You know, candidates for reopening.

Would this be feasible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reopen votes queue seems to show questions that were edited after being closed. As it seems, few users with closed questions edit their posts afterward, so it's grouped into the also quite-small reopen-vote stream.

Of course, I may be wrong about the statistic, and edited questions may sometimes be dropped(if edits aren't large, perhaps), but such things already happen, albeit quite slowly.

Comment: I see. Never realised that; apparently you're right and it doesn't happen all that often, otherwise I might have noticed it!